# How to using calculation of an aggregate function as filter criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, inner-join

I have tables on booking orders

```
Bookings (booking_id, booking_time, driver_id, customer_id)
Drivers (driver_id, name)
```

I need to identify all customers who have had at least half of their bookings completed by the same driver within the last 30 days.

Explanation

- Customer x had 12 bookings, of which 7 of them were completed by driver_01.
- Customer y had 10 bookings, of which 4 of them were completed by driver_02.
- Customer z had 3 booking, of which 3 was completed by driver_03

The output would return driver_01 and driver_03 with booking_id

I have tried using self join and count aggregate, but I still don’t get the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do thiw with window functions:

```
select b.*, d.name as driver_name
from driver d
inner join (
    select b.*, 
        count(*) over(partition by driver_id, customer_id) / count(*) over(partition by customer_id) as driver_ratio
    from booking b
) b on b.driver_id = d.driver_id
where driver_ratio >= 0.6
```

Comment: @user14767369 . . . I think this is the better solution, both in terms of simplicity and performance.

Comment: yeah i think so, I never use partition and count over before, still looking reference for this function. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You correctly identified that a join is useful in getting the total number of bookings per customer so

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BOOKINGS,drivers;

create table Bookings (booking_id int, driver_id int, customer_id varchar(3));

create table Drivers (driver_id int, name varchar(3));

insert into bookings values
(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,2,1),(4,2,1),(5,3,1),
(6,1,2),(7,2,1);

insert into drivers values
(1,'aaa'),(2,'bbb');

select b.driver_id,d.name,b.customer_id,count(*) bcount,scount, count(*) / scount * 100 percent
from bookings b
join (select customer_id,count(*) scount from bookings group by customer_id) s
        on s.customer_id = b.customer_id
join  drivers d on d.driver_id = b.driver_id
group by driver_id,d.name,customer_id having count(*) / scount * 100 >= 50;

+-----------+------+-------------+--------+--------+----------+
| driver_id | name | customer_id | bcount | scount | percent  |
+-----------+------+-------------+--------+--------+----------+
|         1 | aaa  | 2           |      1 |      1 | 100.0000 |
|         2 | bbb  | 1           |      3 |      6 |  50.0000 |
+-----------+------+-------------+--------+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

It's easier to test 50% than 60% - don't forget to change for your requirement.

Comment: Great, So to produce order_id, I can use this as subquery to self join on driver_id and customer_id. Thank You Very much

Answer (score 1):

I have tested @P.Salmon's code as I was also having a similar approach and I find @P.Salmon is answer to be correct, however if you pass in date say for example you only want to return for the last 30 days like you have specified on you question, It might not work

see below

```
SELECT b.booking_date,b.driver_id, d.name, b.customer_id, COUNT(*) b_count, c_count, COUNT(*) / c_count * 100 percent
FROM bookings b 
JOIN (SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) c_count from bookings GROUP BY customer_id) c ON c.customer_id = b.customer_id 
JOIN drivers d ON d.driver_id = b.driver_id 
WHERE b.booking_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY booking_date, driver_id, d.name, customer_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) / c_count * 100 >= 50;
```